# Dynamic Slugs in multilingue website Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I have a multilingue website created using Laravel 4,  and I have lot of pages such as : "policy, "terms", "how it works" in database, so to access thoses pages I use this route:

```
 // Group by locale
 Route::group(
array( 'prefix' => $locale ), function () {
 Route::get('{slug}', array('uses' => 'PageController@show','as' => 'pages.show'); 

 // Website routes

 });
```

And then I search for the given slug and the current locale.

My is problem is that I can't add for example a page link in the footer because the slug is dynamic. so is there any solution to resolve that.

It's make a sense ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'the slug is dynamic' ? isn't it supposed to be dynamic ? can you update the post with `show` method from `PageControllre` class ?

Comment: It means that the slug is not defined in the database instead of  routes.php, so a page have multiple content which means the slug depends the language and the content for example : 
fr : /fr/comment-ca-marche
en : /en/how-it-works, 
es : /como-funciona
, and so on

.so my problem is if i want to put a page link somewhere in the website, i can't know which slug to put.

Comment: @nabill. its not clear what you want..

Answer (score 0):

You are already catching the slug in

```
Route::get('{slug}', array('uses' => 'PageController@show','as' => 'pages.show');
```

part. all you need is to inject this slug into controller like this:

```
class PageController extends BaseController {

    public function show($slug)
    {
        return 'showing slug ' . $slug;
    }
}
```

and whatever value the route receive for `{slug}` part in route laravel will automatically inject that value into the controller.